# How should I modify my code to not get output as 0?

Tags: c

This is a code for input-output practice. I am getting the correct output for the first two input lines. But I am getting a zero for the third line input.
The given task is: To calculate the sum of some integers.

```
Input:
4 1 2 3 4
5 1 2 3 4 5
0
Output:
10
15

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, first, next, total;
    while(scanf("%d", &first) != EOF)
    {
        total = 0;
        for(i = 1; i <= first; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &next);
            total += next;
        }
        printf("%d\n", total);
        if(first == 0)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your  `while` condition is very strange. Did you read the documentation of [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) ? Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). I suggest coding `while(scanf("%d", &first) == 1)`

Comment: And why don't you test the result of `scanf("%d", &next)` with something starting with `if (scanf("%d", &next)==1)` ?

Comment: Thank you. The code is running successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want output when the first number on a line is zero, then you should test `first == 0` **before** calculating and printing a total and break from the loop (`break;` if you want to stop the loop) or continue to the next iteration (`continue;`).